# Applescript Dialog Box, answer not with mouse but just by typing a letter

Tags: macos, applescript

Sometimes you come accross a dialog box in a Mac app that can be answered by typing a letter, e.g. in Logic Pro there are dialog boxes containing a button named "Delete". If you press "d" the dialog closes and the selected part is deleted. How do they do it? I'm trying to create such a dialog box with two buttons saying "Uit" and "Aan". Pressing "u" or "a" should trigger the action.
Thank you!

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? Are you using basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** and the `display dialog` _command_? If yes, then you are out of luck as `display dialog` presents a _modal dialog_ that only responds to _mouse clicks_ or the **enter** _key_ , and _tabbing_and the _space bar_ if **[√] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** is checked in:  **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**

Comment: Hi, I'm on High Sierra, 10.13.6. Thank you for your help.